# What time format is this in (1391468400000)?

Tags: datetime, time

I can't find any reference to what format this could be in. Do you know?

```
<publishStartDate>1391468400000</publishStartDate>
<publishEndDate>1391727599999</publishEndDate>
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is a unix timestamp in millisecond form.

Comment: In UTC, 1391468400.000 = Mon Feb 03 23:00:00.000 2014 and
1391727599.999 = Thu Feb 06 22:59:59.999 2014.  It was probably published in UTC+1 timezone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking at the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970. See the [Wikipedia article on "Unix Time"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Comment: It looks like its in milliseconds

Comment: Specifically they are Mon, 03 Feb 2014 23:00:00 GMT and Thu, 06 Feb 2014 23:00:00 GMT.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess they were Unix Timestamps, given they convert in this site: [Unix Time Stamp Converter](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm)